# DocuSign: set expiration in JWT Token - always get access token with one hour expiration

Tags: jwt, docusignapi

We are developing an integration with DocuSign. We use embedded signing and JWT authentication. 
We received information from DocuSign Partner Solutions team that in JWT authentication, the expiration of the access token can be set by us to a long period of time.

based on that information, I designed the solution so we manually do the JWT authentication flow: get user consent, generate JWT, set expiration to one year and use it to obtain a long expiring access token.

now we went out of sandbox to production. We are testing the solution against a 30 days trail production account. We got user consent. I generate JWT and set expiration to various periods (one day, one month, one year) but I always get an access token that is good for one hour only.

PS, I went through the [official documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken)  which states this about JWT exp property:

> Defaults to one hour from the value of iat, and cannot be set to a greater value.

I wanted to know if anyone was able to generate long expiring access token out of JWT in DocuSign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum grant time for access tokens received via the DocuSign OAuth JWT Grant flow is 1 hour.

The maximum grant time for access tokens received via the DocuSign OAuth Authorization Code Grant flow is 8 hours.

Good news for your application is that it is easy to obtain a new token via the JWT Grant flow: just re-run it within your app when the token that you have is about to expire or has expired.

No interaction with the user is needed since they have already provided consent (a one-time operation).

Note that the JWT Grant flow *can* fail, especially if the user has withdrawn their consent. Be sure to test this situation.

I'm sorry that you were given incorrect information.